# browser.tabs.executeScript in Firefox Extension return value

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

How to return a value in browser.tabs.executeScript in Firefox Extension? I need to access `var selectedText`.

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var test = browser.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: ` var selectedText = ''; if (window.getSelection) { selectedText = window.getSelection(); } else { selectedText = ''};`
  });
  
 alert(test);
```

Also this doesn't work:

```
var test = browser.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: ` window.getSelection.toString()`
  });
  
 alert(test);
```

Output is only [Object Promise] in alert window

[alert window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN08G.png)

Comment: `code: 'window.getSelection().toString()',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now for me:

```
browser.tabs.executeScript({code: "window.getSelection().toString();"}).then(result => { document.getElementById("1").value = result; });
```